# Filter candidates when selecting using lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, filtering, dynamics-crm, lookup

I've resolved this problem in [a complicated way](http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/filtered-lookups-in-crm-2011/) and now I'd be delighted to see if there's a simpler solution.

Suppose that we have two custom entities, *Alpha* and *Beta*, each of which has a custom field called *reference*. If I place two lookups on a form, one for each of the custom entities, all's dandy as long as I don't require the lookup processes to depend on each other.

Now, what if I pick *Alpha* instance (call it *a*) first and then only want to see those *Beta* instances in the search box that share their owner with the selected *a*? That's easy, right? You just customize the filtration of the field.

But what if I want the selection of *Beta* instance to be predicated on the custom *reference* field?

Do I really have to declare a dynamical view to cheat myself around this part? It's so inconvenient and cumbersome...

Comment: You've done it the only way I was aware it could be done.   We can only hope it might be different in CRM 2013 i guess. :-(

Comment: Dang... That's definitely something on my wish-list for Orion. Haven't checked that feature yet. Also, please place your comment as a reply so I can approve it as an answer.

Comment: I can put my comment as the answer. I REALLY hope this isn't the answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done it the only way I was aware it could be done.

We can only hope it might be different in CRM 2013 i guess.